# How to filter observations within a group and from another (reference) `data.frame`

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking to filter out observations within my data based on certain values by group, which is based on a separate table.  I am also trying to work exclusively with `dplyr` whereas I've performed tasks like these with `data.table` and I'm not sure how to accomplish it at all.

Here is some sample data to illustrate:

```
#Primary dataset
dat <- data.frame(account = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7),
              ip = c("255.255.255", 
                     "255.255.255", "199.199.99", "255.255.255",
                     "75.75.75", "120.120.120",
                     "50.50.50"),
              value = c(50, 1000, 800, 2500, 3000, 500, 75))
```

From the dataset, I would like to filter based on a list of IPs **per account**, which is another table:

```
#Filtering reference table
exclude <- data.frame(account = c(3, 5),
                  ip = c("255.255.255", "120.120.120"))
```

The desired output of `dat` after filtering would be:

```
   account          ip value
 1       1 255.255.255    50
 2       3  199.199.99   800
 3       5    75.75.75  3000
 4       7    50.50.50    75
```

I am specifically unsure how to include the reference in a `group_by` within a piped (`%>%`) series of `dplyr` verbs on `dat`.  I also may be approaching the task incorrectly given I am still familiarizing with the `dplyr` style of programming, so am open to a different way than the reference approach I am considering as long as it is within `dplyr`.

Comment: I would look into dplyr's `_join` family functions

Comment: Indeed, the `anti_join` does precisely this with the command `dat %>% anti_join(exclude)` or explicitly with `dat %>% anti_join(exclude, by = c("account", "ip"))`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

`dat %>% 
mutate(accountip = paste0(account, ip)) %>% 
filter(!(accountip %in% paste0(exclude$account,exclude$ip))) %>% 
select(account, ip, value)`

Comment: This seems quite verbose compared to `anti_join(dat, exclude)` which is one option from the link Camille posted.

Comment: Fully agree.  This could be a useful approach in the case where the dataframes your filtering on don't have the exact same structure/columns.